# Disassembling code and finding the length of `la`

Tags: assembly, mips, disassembly

Given the MIPS assembly and its disassembly below. How long is the `la` instruction? Why is the `la` instruction translated to `lui` (load upper immediate)? Why is it loading a negative number?

MIPS assembly:

```
la $t1,addr1
lw $t1,($t1)
```

Disassembly:

```
0x9D00024C: LUI T1, -24576
0x9D000254: LW T1, 0(T1)
```

Is the length determined by subtracting `0x9D000254-0x9D00024C`? I'm not sure why `la` is translated into `lui` though and why it's negative.

Comment: Because presumably the address of `addr1` is 0xA0000000 (you haven't shown us that), and `lui t1,-24576` is the same as `lui t1,0xA000`. The disassembler you're using just decided to show the number as signed.

Comment: Every MIPS instruction is one word long. But `la` is not MIPS instruction, it's pseudo-instruction compiled by assembler into real instructions "as needed", depends on the address value. If that address would require full 32b number stored in instruction, it would be compiled as `lui + ori` IIRC, but your address is trivial enough to be constructed by `lui` only. (obviously? you can't put full 32b value into 32b instruction, you would have 0 bits left to specify the instruction itself)

Comment: @Ped7g, thanks for the response. One last question: is the length of `la` instruction calculated as follows `0x9D000254-0x9D00024C`?

Comment: @user7187525 oh, I (and Michael too) missed that completely, excellent eye for detail. A) yes, sort of, what you wrote is length of pseudo-instruction, ie. length of code block supporting its functionality done in native instructions. The native ins. are still 1 word only on MIPS CPU (fixed size ins. set). B) 0x54-0x4C = 8, so there are two instructions, and that disassembly is hiding the other one (which will be probably `ori`). If you are using something like MARS/SPIM, search through it's options/views to see full native-instruction level disassembly (MARS has one for 100%, I used it once).